# Making bash profile visible for non login shell

Tags: linux

I have a .bash_profile and I have several commands in this shell. I have logged in as user1. Now in my terminal, I do a su - user2.

When I'm with user2, I'm not able to call these commands that I have created in the .bash_profile. How could I make the PATH elements and environment variables visible to user2 as well? When I do an echo $PATH when using user2, I get this:

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin

When I do an echo $PATH using user1, I get a lot more. How do I make this additional PATH elements also visible for user1?

Comment: You could use `source ~user1/.bash_profile` to execute your profile.

Comment: The user2 is a postgres user and I could not get the home directory!

Comment: @spakr As I've said in the answer below, try 'su postgres' (without minus)

Comment: This gives me a bash shell. Which user is that? Will it be the postgres user?

Comment: Is there an alternative? I do not want to use su without minus!

Comment: `su postgres` switches to the postgres user entirely. It gives the users' shell and all permissions. The only difference is that the shell initialization files are not executed. The only alternative that I can imagine is to store everything you need in a readable by both users file and execute that file by the second (postgres in your case) user.

Comment: Where would that location be? Somewhere inside the /etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`su <user>` (without `-`) does not read the **< user >**'s shell initialization files. Thus leaving the previous users' settings.

Comment: His complaint is that he's NOT getting the previous user's settings.

Comment: That's what I meant. He should run 'su <user>' and that he will get what was in the old users's shell